# ajax call to php to do only an insert on mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, insert

I need to call a php file from a javscript function by ajax and do an insert in a table on load my page. I´m doing this but the javascript function call my php file and when end the execution of all the sentences on the php file not return to my javascript funtion only show a withe page.

I don't want to return any value form the php file...only finish that insert and charge the  of the page that is contains in the same file php that conteins the javascripts functions.

The call to the files is doing by the function "guardar_alerta" and this call to "realizar_peticion"

```js
function realizar_peticion(url, metodo, funcion)
{
  peticionHTML.onreadystatechange = funcion;
  peticionHTML.open(metodo, url, true);
  peticionHTML.send(null);
}

function guardar_alerta(lat)
{
  realizar_peticion("../sites/all/modules/custom/gestion_usuarios/includes/usuario/aviso.php?lat="+lat,"GET",funcion_actuadora);
}
```

Here the Javascript code

```js
function inicializar_XHR()
{
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    peticionHTML = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else
    peticionHTML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function realizar_peticion(url, metodo, funcion)
{
  peticionHTML.onreadystatechange = funcion;
  peticionHTML.open(metodo, url, true);
  peticionHTML.send(null);
}

function guardar_alerta(lat)
{
  realizar_peticion("../sites/all/modules/custom/gestion_usuarios/includes/usuario/aviso.php?lat="+lat,"GET",funcion_actuadora);
}

function funcion_actuadora() {
  if(peticionHTML.readyState == 4)
    if(peticionHTML.status == 200)
      alert("IS done!");
}

function sendToPhp()
{
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      inicializar_XHR();
      guardar_alerta(lat);

}
```

this is the php file that is call by ajax ...aviso.php

```html
<?php
$lat = $_GET['lat'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "delmontag");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM dt_producto";
$sql_query="INSERT INTO dt_aviso (id_producto, latitud) VALUES(1, '4666663')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Thanks for all yours answers.

Comment: How do you call `sendToPhp()`?

Comment: i forgot that 


window.onload = function() {
    sendToPhp();
};

Comment: I really, really, recommend jQuery for ajax instead of trying to capture the readyState.

Comment: So, you are expecting the `alert("IS done!")` to fire?

Comment: really, i don't want an alert i put that alert only for do some "debug". I need that aviso.php finish and charge the page where is the caller function (javascript)

Comment: @Drakes with  jaquery you think that  i can find the solution?

Comment: Help me understand a little better. So, your page with the JS loads, sends an Ajax request to the PHP page, it is successful (200 response) and then what should happen?

Comment: What do you see in the error console? And where do you declare `position`? When I run this code, it fails because `position` is not defined. As it is the first command inside `sendToPhp()`, the execution stops and the PHP file is not called. If I harcode the value of `lat`, the call is done